# Cannot set up a tcp session to an azure worker role listener when debugging locally

Tags: debugging, azure, tcp, azure-worker-roles, tcplistener

I have a SocketListener running in an azure worker role. It works fine but I want to debug locally. I can connect to the worker role using localhost but cannot connect from remote clients.
I have tested the router and incoming firewall by using a tcp terminal program I have switched off the firewall on my development pc.

Please can you help me to get remote clients to connect to a worker role listener being debugged on the development machine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The local windows azure development emulator is not designed to support remote connections. I would suggest deploying the application to Windows Azure and remotely debugging to test your scenario.